# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC not loading CSS styles

Tags: c#, css, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, the `.css` file is not working in the view file.

I ran .NET externally as html file and it worked without any problems.

[image]

Comment: Please don´t add code as image [edit] and add it as formatted text to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, the .css file is not working in the
> view file.

As you may know, Static files are stored within the project's web root directory.And the default directory is `{content root}/wwwroot`, You can refer to the official [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about static files.

**Inside wwwroot:**

Thus, You need to put your css files either in folder into wwwroot like following:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then try to use:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

In Program.cs file include the reference:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**Outside wwwroot:**

Furthermore, if you want to serve files outside of the web root in that scenario,  Consider below directory hierarchy :

**Program.cs**

Include reference as following in your program.cs file:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "StaticFilesFolderName")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFilesFolderName"
});
```

Use Reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/StaticFilesFolderName/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

**Note:**

As per your scenario, it would be AdminLTE... so on and follow the accurate path. For more details and example please [have a look our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)